# Dynamic row file name into textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

Using jquery and bootstrap-jasny I created a dynamic row insert:

[Code here](http://jsfiddle.net/z7vfxvmo/4/)

html:

```
<table id="internalTbl">
    <tr><td><div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput"> <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select file</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
    <input type="file" name="name">
    </span> <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
 <a href="#" class="close fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput" style="float: none">&times;</a>
    <input type="text" name="namehidden" />
        </td></tr>
</table>
        <button id="addInternal"> add </button>
```

javascript:

```
    // add new row to internal listing table
    $("#addInternal").click(function() {
        $("#internalTbl").each(function () {
            var tds = '<tr>';
            $.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
                tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
            });
            tds += '</tr>';

            if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            } else {
                $(this).append(tds);
            }
        });

        // clear the last file input field
        $("#internalTbl tr:last .fileinput").fileinput('clear');
    });
```

For the subsequence, I am not able to assign the file name to the textbox.

Comment: what is `fileinput()`. What errors are thrown? ID's must be unique so not sure why you have `$("#internalTbl").each` since there can only be one element that matches that selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delegate the change event for dynamically added fileinput. [More on delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). The below code will attach the change event on future elements with class `.fileinput`

```
$(document).on('change.bs.fileinput', '.fileinput', function (e) {
    var filename = $(this).closest('tr').find('.fileinput-filename').text();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').val(filename);
});
```

Also I have used two methods of appending, one on click creates the trs and tds manually and other [clones](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the first tr and appends to the table. You can use any one.

```
var fileinput = $('#internalTbl tr td:eq(0)').html();
var td = '<td>'+fileinput+'</td>';
var tr ='<tr>'+ td+'</tr>';


$("#addInternal").click(function () {
    $("#internalTbl tbody").append(tr);
    $("#internalTbl tr:last .fileinput").fileinput('clear');
});

$("#addInternal2").click(function () {  
    var cloned_elem = $('#internalTbl tr:first').clone();
    $("#internalTbl tbody").append(cloned_elem);
    $("#internalTbl tr:last .fileinput").fileinput('clear');
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z7vfxvmo/8/)